# File explorer randomly opens after any command in git bash

Tags: laravel, bash, git, terminal

I am working on a laravel project and literally, after any command in the git bash file explorer randomly opens few times.

If I run npm run dev, npm install, PHP artisan something...

[image]

Here is the package.json:

[image]

Comment: Could you add your `package.json` file?

Comment: @MaartenDev Question edited :)

Comment: You added the `composer.json`, I was looking for the `package.json` file ;)

Comment: LOL my bad :D Will edit question again xD

Comment: @MaartenDev Question edited :D

Comment: What version of node are you using? `node -v`?, Did you check your `PATH` environment variable value?

Comment: @MaartenDev node version is 15.11.0 and what do you mean by PATH? How to check that?

Answer (score 1):

> What do you mean by PATH? How to check that?

If you are on Windows:

- open a CMD
- type `set PATH`
- type `where find`

And error like find: `/I` no such file or directory looks like a Linux `find` used where a Windows `find.exe` (using such options as `/I`)  is expected.

If `where find` returns two path entries, the order of those paths would be important.

Comment: Interestingly enough I cant even open cmd now ... it just closes it automatically

Comment: @SeadSilajdzic Whut?  Wrong `AutoRun` entry in the registry, as seen in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fL9oElitx6I?

Comment: @SeadSilajdzic Or worse... https://stackoverflow.com/q/5373137/6309. But on AutoRun, see also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZiQ4bPgwVk or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpuACtGl5q8