# Issue creating new process cmd.exe, opens and then closes immediately VB6/Windows 10

Tags: cmd, windows-10, vb6

When i run the following code to create a cmd.exe process in windows 10, the console application opens and then closes immediately. In windows 7 this is working fine.

If i run calc.exe, this process does not closes immediately, this just happens with cmd.exe.

```
Const NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H20&
Dim lSuccess            As Long
Dim sApplicationName    As String
Dim sCommandLine        As String
Dim wCurrentDirectory   As String
Dim pInfo               As PROCESS_INFORMATION
Dim sInfo               As STARTUPINFO

sApplicationName = "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
sCommandLine = ""
wCurrentDirectory = "C:\Windows\system32"
    
lSuccess = CreateProcess(sApplicationName, _
                            sCommandLine, _
                            ByVal 0&, _
                            ByVal 0&, _
                            0&, _
                            NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, _
                            ByVal 0&, _
                            wCurrentDirectory, _
                            sInfo, _
                            pInfo)
```

**EDIT:**

After some debug i have found the problem, when its invoked SetParent function (after Create Process) the cmd.exe closes, but not calc.exe.

This SetParent function is declared in this way

```
Public Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndChild As Long, ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long
```

*hWndChild* is the window handle ID of cmd.exe or calc.exe, and *hWndNewParent* is the window handle ID of the parent in this case the application that (indirectly) runs this code.

Comment: This code works for me.

Comment: Work's fine for me too.  Is there more code that is not listed?

Comment: You can also try `Shell ("cmd.exe /k")` of `Shell ("cmd.exe /k " + strMyCmd)`

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373137/cmd-exe-closes-immediately-after-calling-win7-64) would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, i have found that SetParent from user32 lib is causing this issue, but just for cmd.exe

Comment: @Pl4tinum Please see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683 then.